# IO Redirection in Linux Bash shell scripts not recreating moved/deleted file?

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I am quite new to shell programming on Linux and in my Linux instance, I am redirecting the stdout and stderr of a program to two files in following manner and run it in background

```
myprog > run.log 2>> err.log &
```

This works fine, and I get my desired behavior

Now there is a another background process that monitors the run.log and err.log, and moves them to other file names, if the log files grow beyond a certain threshold.

e.g. `mv err.log err[date-time].log`

my expectation is that after this file move happens, err.log will be created again by the myprog output redirection and new output will be written to that new file. However, after my log file monitoring process moves the file, err.log or run.log never get created again although myprog continues to run without any issues.

Is this the normal behavior in Linux? If it is, what should I do to get my expected behavior working?

Comment: File handles are tied to inodes, not filenames. Changes to which name on the filesystem, if any, an inode is linked to are completely transparent. This is very desirable behavior -- it's why, for instance, you can upgrade software packages on UNIXlike operating systems while that software is in use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is. Unless you first program reopen the files, it will keep writing to the old file, even if you can't access it anymore. In fact, the space used by that removed file will only be available after every process closes it. If reopening it is not possible (ie. you can't change the executable nor restart it), then a solution like http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html is your best bet.
It can rotate logs based on filesize or time, and even call a custom script after a rotation.

Example usage:

```
myprog | rotatelogs logname.log 50M
```

This way the log will be rotated whenever the size reaches 50 megabytes.

[EDIT: pointed to a newer version of rotatelogs]

Comment: This isn't wrong, but I'd argue that it's incomplete -- doesn't provide any hints on how to restart logging on a shell script without restarting the script as a whole. `rotatelogs`, like `logrotate`, will do the rotation for you, but you still need to signal the use of a new destination file.

Comment: it does not need the signal, and that's exactly the reason I stated "If reopening it is not possible (ie. you can't change the executable nor restart it), ". The actual usage would be "myprog | rotatelogs <parameters>". This way, it's rotatelogs that will do the rotation and reopen the files.

Comment: Ahh. Makes perfect sense in that usage mode.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it actually associates the process that is logging with a file descriptor, not a file name. When you rename it, you only change the file name. So the process just keeps logging to the file.  Just a guess. If I were tasked with fixing it, I would stop the logging process and restart it at that point to re-associate it with the right file.

Just a guess.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I just noticed that the behavior is exactly what you explained here. After the mv command, my file still keeps growing. Now that I know this behavior, I will be able to come up with a solution that probably involving file copy (cp) rather than moving and also truncating the original file.

Comment: @user1824801, using `cp` is going to open you up to race conditions. Moving the original file and then using a signal handler to trigger a reopen of the log destination is actually how it's done with Apache and other professionally-used software for the purpose.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Charles Duffy. I realized that cp, and truncate will lead to a race condition and if myprog wins over my log monitor, I will lose some log statements in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Software with support for log rotation actually has support *written in* for this rotation. If you look at `man logrotate`, you'll notice that a typical configuration looks like this:

```
   "/var/log/httpd/access.log" /var/log/httpd/error.log {
       rotate 5
       mail www@my.org
       size 100k
       sharedscripts
       postrotate
           /usr/bin/killall -HUP httpd
       endscript
   }
```

...which is to say that it sends a HUP signal to the program whose log has been rotated; that program has a *signal handler* that reopens its output files.

---

You can do this in your shell scripts too:

```
reopen_logs() {
  exec >>run.log 2>>err.log
}
trap reopen_logs HUP
```

...then, after rotating your logs, run `kill -HUP pid_of_yourscript`; on the next occasion when the script itself is executing a command (since signal handlers only run between foregrounded executables), it will reopen its output to recreate the log file without needing to restart.